# Is my mfacebook object initialized well?

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I have integrated facebook into my android application. Below is the code:

```
public class Example extends Activity {


public static final String APP_ID = "My App ID";//i have placed my app id here

private LoginButton mLoginButton;
private TextView mText;
private Button mPostButton;


private Facebook mFacebook;
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (APP_ID == null) {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be " +
                "specified before running this example: see Example.java");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mText = (TextView) Example.this.findViewById(R.id.txt);

    mPostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);

    **mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);**//this is where i get a Null Pointer Exception
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);

    SessionStore.restore(mFacebook, this);
    SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new SampleAuthListener());
    SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new SampleLogoutListener());
    mLoginButton.init(this, mFacebook);



    mPostButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mFacebook.dialog(Example.this, "feed",
                    new SampleDialogListener());
        }
    });
    mPostButton.setVisibility(mFacebook.isSessionValid() ?
            View.VISIBLE :
            View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```

When I run the app I get a null pointer exception at line:
  **mfacebook = new facebook(APP_ID);**

This is my Logcat

> 06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sardarjijokes.ncpl/com.sardarjijokes.ncpl.Example}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at com.sardarjijokes.ncpl.Example.onCreate(Example.java:85)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   06-27 15:01:29.424: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(646):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

Please provide suggestions.

Comment: are you sure APP_ID  is not null means your are not getting  Util.showAlert . if yes then please the log cat.........

Comment: Here's my suggestion: provide the logcat output

Comment: added logcat..example.java 85th line is the line i have highlighted in the code above.

Comment: My bad i was referring to a different layout.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main); //set Activity layout here
    if (APP_ID == null) {
        Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be " +
                "specified before running this example: see Example.java");
    }


    mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
    mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);

    mPostButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postButton);

    **mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);**//this is where i get a Null Pointer Exception
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
```

Comment: My bad i was referring to a different layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code, if the `APP_ID` is null you show a warning message but let the rest of the code get executed.

Shouldn't it be:

```
if (APP_ID == null) {
    Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be " + "specified before running this example: see Example.java");
    return;
}
```

?